# Problem about water and time

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, word-problem

You can fill a container with water from a hot water tap in $80$ minutes. The container can be filled with water from a cold water tap in $48$ minutes. How long does it take to fill the tub, if you use both faucets?

Comment: probability tag?

Comment: Convert from "minutes per tank" to "tanks per minute". Then add the two. Then convert back.

Comment: The tags that you use should describe the question you are asking.  Check to make sure the tags you use are related to the question you are asking instead of picking one at random.  [Read more about tags here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/tagging).  Also, [see the list of tags here](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags) giving you an idea of which tags are popular in case you aren't sure how to describe your question.

Answer (score 1):

So the hot water tap fills $1 \over 80$ of the container in one minute and the cold water $1\over 48$. Together they fill $1\over 30$ of the container in one minute which means they need $30$ minutes to fill it together.